# Problem in creating boxplots with R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, statistics, visualization, boxplot

I'm very new to the Shiny app R. I'm trying to make simple boxplots in the Shiny R app for some dataset.

Here I am showing some example data in a file `df.csv`. The data looks like below. Showing the `dput` of the data below:

```
structure(list(Samples = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Sample1", 
"Sample10", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", 
"Sample7", "Sample8", "Sample9"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Normal", "Tumor"
), class = "factor"), A1BG = c(0, 0.01869105, 0.026705782, 0.016576987, 
0, 0.007636787, 0.015756547, 0.00609601, 0.115575528, 0.04717536
), A1BG.AS1 = c(0, 0.096652515, 0.086710002, 0.04683499, 0.188283185, 
0.104318353, 0.102735593, 0.100064808, 0.04717536, 0.159745808
), A1CF = c(1.616942802, 1.367084444, 1.101855892, 1.3823884, 
0.631627098, 2.407159505, 1.687449785, 1.229844138, 0.87989414, 
0.642785868), A2M = c(3.357654845, 3.149165846, 3.654774122, 
2.851143092, 2.952601867, 4.002335454, 4.123949457, 3.691343955, 
3.553064673, 3.425443559), A2M.AS1 = c(0.217308191, 0.08268571, 
0.297320544, 0.101579093, 0.020102613, 0.35578965, 0.288014115, 
0.145352771, 0.043808388, 0.104677012), A2ML1 = c(0, 0.017949113, 
0.00984907, 0.002289616, 0, 0.002100359, 0.032146138, 0.052275569, 
0.537892142, 0), A2ML1.AS1 = c(0.631627098, 0.04717536, 1.229844138, 
0, 4.002335454, 0, 1.229844138, 1.229844138, 0.04717536, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

With the above information, I am trying to make a shiny app. My code looks like below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("thegene", "Gene", choices = c("A2M", "A1CF", "A2MP1"), selected = "A2M"),
      radioButtons("colour","Colour of histogram",choices=c("red","green","blue"),selected="red"),
      width = 3
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("boxplot"),
      width = 9
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- read.csv("df.csv")

  library(reshape2)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggpubr)
  library(EnvStats)

  df.m <- melt(df, c("Samples", "Type"))

  output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=df.m, aes(x = Type, y = value, fill=variable)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      theme_bw(base_size = 14) + xlab("") + ylab("Expression logFPKM") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black"),
            axis.title=element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black"),
            strip.text = element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black")) +
      stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", size=5) + stat_n_text()
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So, I reshaped the information and then tried making an app to create a boxplot for each gene between Tumor (6 samples) and Normal (4 samples).

I don't see any error, but I also don't get the desired result. The output of my above code looks like below:

[image]

1) The number of samples in the boxplot below each Type is wrong.

2) For the Selection of genes, I could see only three genes there. I don't see other genes there. How to check for other genes?

3) The color of the histogram is also not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Error in reshape2::melt(final, c("Samples", "Type")) : object 'final' not found`

Comment: Can you get the boxplot to look as expected on the console? If not, then I suggest you remove `shiny` from this question and focus on the basics. (I can't verify now because of the `final` error.)

Comment: @r2evans sorry just now updated the code. Please check the code now.

Comment: I think my second comment is still relevant, though ... and since I don't have `EnvStats`, it's difficult to know if that's causing me any issues here. Can you generate the plot you expect on the console? Your code here does not use anything that `shiny` offers, so that seems odd. Also, you statically define the number of genes available in the `selectInput`; if you want them dynamically assigned when the data is loaded, use `shiny::updateSelectInput`.

Comment: I actually have a big dataset. And I want to create a shiny app for that. Here I'm showing some example data. shiny::updateSelectInput throws an error. Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: I don't know how you're using it, but ... there should not be any use of `input$` in that call, if that's what you're doing. Something like `updateSelectInput(session, "thegene", unique(df.m$variable))`, though you need to change to `server <- function(input, output, session) {...}`.

Comment: For your point 3, this goes along with a previous comment: you provide the radio buttons *but never use their value*, so no color is going to change. If you aren't certain how to use these input values from `shiny` in code that changes data-filtering and plot colors, then I strongly suggest you spend a few minutes looking at the tutorials and documentation at https://shiny.rstudio.com/, as that is much more of a "tutorial" function than SO is meant to support/provide.

Comment: sorry not working for me. Did you try using that way and are you able to create an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

I made a few changes, you might keep some and reverse others.

1. I do not have `ggpubr` or `EnvStats`, so I removed some of the plotting summaries.
2. I have static data defined, you should likely return to your `read.csv` solution.
3. I added `session` to the server declaration, required if you want to update any inputs programmatically.
4. I have an inefficient reactive block that just returns all of the original data; as it stands now, this is anti-idiomatic, but was added solely to demonstrate the proper use of `updateSelectInput` if/when the source data changes. This is necessary only if your data changes dynamically (e.g., user-uploads data or a database query), otherwise `alldat()` should really just be `df.m` (and your input should be defined statically).
5. I updated the use of the color radio button.

```r
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(EnvStats)

df <- structure(list(Samples = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Sample1", 
"Sample10", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", 
"Sample7", "Sample8", "Sample9"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Normal", "Tumor"
), class = "factor"), A1BG = c(0, 0.01869105, 0.026705782, 0.016576987, 
0, 0.007636787, 0.015756547, 0.00609601, 0.115575528, 0.04717536
), A1BG.AS1 = c(0, 0.096652515, 0.086710002, 0.04683499, 0.188283185, 
0.104318353, 0.102735593, 0.100064808, 0.04717536, 0.159745808
), A1CF = c(1.616942802, 1.367084444, 1.101855892, 1.3823884, 
0.631627098, 2.407159505, 1.687449785, 1.229844138, 0.87989414, 
0.642785868), A2M = c(3.357654845, 3.149165846, 3.654774122, 
2.851143092, 2.952601867, 4.002335454, 4.123949457, 3.691343955, 
3.553064673, 3.425443559), A2M.AS1 = c(0.217308191, 0.08268571, 
0.297320544, 0.101579093, 0.020102613, 0.35578965, 0.288014115, 
0.145352771, 0.043808388, 0.104677012), A2ML1 = c(0, 0.017949113, 
0.00984907, 0.002289616, 0, 0.002100359, 0.032146138, 0.052275569, 
0.537892142, 0), A2ML1.AS1 = c(0.631627098, 0.04717536, 1.229844138, 
0, 4.002335454, 0, 1.229844138, 1.229844138, 0.04717536, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
df.m <- reshape2::melt(df, c("Samples", "Type"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("thegene", "Gene", choices = c("A2M", "A1CF", "A2MP1"), selected = "A2M"),
      radioButtons("colour","Colour of histogram",choices=c("red","green","blue"),selected="red"),
      width = 3
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("boxplot"),
      width = 9
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  alldat <- reactive({
    # this is not an efficient use of a reactive block: since it does
    # not depend on any dynamic data, it will fire only once, so if
    # your data is static then this might be a touch overkill ... but
    # the premise is that your `df.m` is data that can change based on
    # updating it (e.g., DB query) or user-uploaded data (e.g., CSV
    # upload)
    choices <- unique(df.m$variable)
    selected <- isolate(input$thegene)
    if (!selected %in% choices) selected <- choices[1]
    updateSelectInput(session, "thegene", choices = choices, selected = selected)
    df.m
  })

  dat <- reactive({
    x <- alldat()
    x[ x$variable == input$thegene,,drop=FALSE]
  })

  output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = dat(), aes(x = Type, y = value, fill = variable)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      theme_bw(base_size = 14) + xlab("") + ylab("Expression logFPKM") +
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black"),
            axis.title=element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black"),
            strip.text = element_text(size=15, face = "bold", color = "black")) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = input$colour)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Some notes/opinions:

- When there is dynamic data due to filtering or user-supplied modifiers, I find it nice to have a reactive block that does *just* the filtering/modifying, so that the modified data can be used in multiple dependent reactive blocks, ergo my `dat <- reactive(...)`
- More the point, I find many not-so-good shiny apps that try to do way too much in a single reactive block; when I see a lot going on, I tend to think either (a) split the reactive block into smaller ones, especially when code is repeated in multiple blocks; and/or (b) write external functions that do most of that work, so that the shiny app itself appears more compact. Declarative function names can make readability/maintainability much easier (and can be unit-tested!).
- I have *not* added any safeguards to this; one such safeguard (though this app does not show it right away) would be the use of `req()` to ensure that the inputs have "stabilized" during startup. With larger apps, one might notice that a few reactive blocks fire before (say) `input$thegene` has a valid value, which can cause some plots/tables to flicker.
- When there is a select input that will quickly be over-written/updated, I generally go with something like `choices="(initializing)"` or something similar; in this case, having reasonable default choices makes sense as long as those choices are very likely or certain to be present in the real data.

Comment: I'm trying to add download plot for the code, but it doesn't work. Any Idea? output$downloadplot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "plot.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      pdf(file, width = 12, height = 6.3)
      print(output())
      dev.off()
    })

Comment: I'll re-suggest looking at the shiny tutorials. If they don't do it, SO has many questions that relate to `downloadHandler`. If none of that works, that's a new question.

Comment: (I will admit that the not-so-common thing in your comment is how to download a PDF rendition of a ggplot object. Your use of `output()` is not going to work, as `output` includes a lot more than just the plot.)

Comment: yes, you are right. I will check the tutorials and if it works I will let you know. thankyou